# Using lambda shared utilities layer in local development

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-lambda-layers

I am using Typescript, Nodejs and sam-beta-cdk to develop a serverless application infrastructure. I would like to share utility functions between my lambdas so I don't have to write the same code over and over again.

File structure looks something like this:

```
lambdas > feature > lambda-name > lambda.js

layers > layer-name > nodejs > utils.js
```

This works very well in aws environment, however, not sure how to integrate Lambda Layers into my local development workflow.

How can I import the utilities from the layer so that it works both in aws as well as my local env?

Answer (score 3):

Update the **compilerOptions** in the **tsconfig.json** of the lambda, add baseUrl and Paths :

```
 "baseUrl": ".",
 "paths": {
      "/opt/nodejs/*": [
        "RelativePathToUtilModule/*",
        "RelativePathToAdditionalCustomLayers/*"
      ]
    }
```

The lambda code can then use the exported members of util/other custom layers which will work for both locally and when deployed to AWS

```
import * as layer1 from "/opt/nodejs/Util";
import * as layer2 from "/opt/nodejs/SomeOtherUtility";
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you will be uploading the layer as a Zip to create the layer during deployment, the best method is to have a step in your pipeline that creates these zips from the appropriate directory in your repo. This can easily be done with makefile util run during a codebuild.

```
utilities_layer
    mkdir node_modules
    cp -R utilities node_modules
    zip -r utilities-layer.zip node_modules
    (clean up if you want to here)
```

Then, in your lambdas you can reference that directory as part of your import statements.

Then for instance you have this structure:

```
|
|-utilities
   |-aws
      |-s3.js
   |-api
|-myLambda
   |-index.js
   |-myLambdaUtil.js
```

Then in your code you would do something like

```
import s3 from utilities.aws
import myLambdaUtil
```

Note that, assuming your lambdas each have their own directory and you are referencing that directory in your deployment solution (CDK, SAM, Cloudformation templates) then the file that are in the same directory *do not include the base root directory* but your utilities do.

This strategy allow you to reference your utilities directory locally with ease, and keeps a similar import pattern as needed for the local env inside the lambda once deployed.

***Please note: Ive been working in Python for the last year and barely touched Node, my node syntax may be a bit rusty but the general idea is the same.***

Comment: That's a great idea! Not currently using a pipeline for deploying my cdk - just doing it with cli which does the zipping for me - but I'll definitely try this. Sounds legit. Thanks!

Comment: Given that you can still utilize a makefile in your local env, it can be very useful with the CLI as well. I have several scripts in my teams repo that activate the make file, then activate the CDK command line to deploy a test env to the cloud with their current local code. For changes that are radical or for new resources this can be really useful as a final layer of manual testing before merging.  (or because you're just not sure how the cloud will differ from your local!)